# Finite-dimensional graded Lie algebras with $2$ generators

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Does anyone know of a classification of those (complex) Lie algebras which are:

1. generated by two elements
2. $\mathbb{Z}$-graded Lie algebras
3. finite dimensional

Comment: There's not even a known classification of 8-dimensional complex Lie algebras graded in positive integers.

Comment: ... and also $\mathbf{Z}$-graded Lie algebras include all Lie algebras $\mathfrak{g}$, graded as $\mathfrak{g}_0$.